# Why the dictionary value is printed in this Python Crash Course exercise?

Tags: python

I tried to searching for it, but can't find what I need.
I'm new to Python, and programming in general, and in the book [*Python Crash Course*](https://nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse2e) chapter 6, I'm stuck trying to understand this code:

```
favorite_languages = {
'jen': 'python',
'sarah': 'c',
'edward': 'ruby',
'phil': 'python',
}

friends = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(f"Hi, {name.title()}")

if name in friends:
    language = favorite_languages[name].title()
    print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")
```

My problem is exactly in this line:

```
language = favorite_languages[name].title()
```

I can't understand why, when it prints the next line in the for loop, `language` prints the value of the dictionary instead of the key.

Maybe it's a really dumb question and I'm missing something told me in some other place in the book, but I'm really struggling to figure this out. I tried rereading previous chapters of PCC, googling and reading the `pydoc`, but failed to get a answer. So would someone here please explain this to me?

Comment: `name` is the key. Why would `favorite_languages[name]` give the key back? No lookup is required if you need the key since you already have `name`.

Comment: So this line is associating the variable `language` to the value related to the key `name`?
Thank you!!!

Comment: `favorite_languages[name]` says "give me the value in `favorite_languages` associated with the `name` key".

Answer (score 0):

Name is a string, in this case, either 'phil' or 'sarah', since those are the two values in the array friends. The whole point of creating the dictionary was that you can take the key, and reach whatever value it is assigned to in the dictionary. For example, on its first loop, name is equal to 'phil'. It goes into the dictionary, checks what value 'phil' is *linked* to, and sets it to that. In dictionaries, when you do this:

```
print(dictionary_name[key])
```

It will print the value whatever that *key* is linked to.